# NSMutableDictionary & dispatch_async Native Objects C# equivalent or similar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm fairly new to xamarin and mobile dev. I'm currently migrating geofire library by Firebase to xamarin.ios. I came across the following objective-c code and trying to figure out what is actually doing? and its c# equivalent:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *keyEnteredObservers;
```

...

```
GFQueryLocationInfo *info = self.locationInfos[key];

[self.keyEnteredObservers enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id observerKey,
                                                                      GFQueryResultBlock block,
                                                                      BOOL *stop) {
        dispatch_async(self.geoFire.callbackQueue, ^{         // the callbackQueue is of type @property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t callbackQueue;
            block(key, info.location);
        });
    }];
```

for the callbackQueue I am currently using type BlockingCollection<'Task>

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NSMutableDictionary.enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock` in this context is doing two basic things.

- It filters the dictionary based on an key. (A Linq `Where` would work as a C# replacement)
- The filtered elements of the dictionary are available to a "block" of code as it is executed asynchronously(`dispatch_async`) via GCD (Grand Central Dispatch). So you are already using a `BlockingCollection` as a Task pump, so pass the `key` string that is a parameter to `updateLocationInfo` and the `CLLocation` to your Task...

Note: The `stop` boolean will cause an early exit from the enumerator, so a C# `break` as a replacement, but it is not used in this context...

If you are still using a `NSMutableDictionary` for your observers, you can filter via `KeysForObject`. In my version of `GeoFire`, I used a `BlockingCollection<Action>` vs. Tasks thus added the lambdas directly to the work queue.

Something like:

```
foreach (var info in keyEnteredObservers.KeysForObject(firebaseHandle))
{
    var nonCapturedLocation = info.location.Copy(); // location = CLLocation, do not capture entire dictionary by ref in lambda
    callbackQueue.Add(() =>
    {
        GFQueryResultBlock(key, nonCapturedLocation);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm still using NSMutableDictionary, this is exactly what I need. Thank you.